# @@@ ABORTING: INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree addr=0x00000156

Tags: java, android

I have begun to try and keep some data persistant in my views when my device is rotated. Since implementing this after awhile my app will crash with the error:

```
@@@ ABORTING: INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree addr=0x00000156
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 20787 (FinalizerDaemon)
```

After the app crashed every time I try to reopen it i get this same error instantly until I uninstall the app.

Does anyone know what causes this error?

Here is the code I used to save my data:

**`onDestory()`:**

```
    System.out.println("Saving");
    ArrayList<Path> strokes = paintCanvas.strokes;
    ArrayList<Integer> colors = paintCanvas.colors;
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("colors", MODE_PRIVATE);
    settings.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);



    /**Write Colors**/
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream os = openFileOutput("drawing.dat", MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
        output.writeObject(colors);
        output.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /**Write Paths**/
    try
    {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        File file = getFileStreamPath("paths.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        for(Path p : strokes)
        {
            String s = gson.toJson(p);
            s = s + "\n";
            output.write(s);
        }

        output.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

**In `onCreate()`:**

```
    //Try Load here!
    /**Read Colors**/
    try
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> colors;
        ArrayList<Path> strokes;
        FileInputStream ins = openFileInput("drawing.dat");
        ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(ins);
        colors = (ArrayList<Integer>)reader.readObject();

        paintCanvas.colors = colors;
        System.out.println("Colors Loaded");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /**Read Paths**/
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("paths.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {   
            paths.add(gson.fromJson(line,Path.class));
        }


        paintCanvas.strokes = paths;
        paintCanvas.currentStroke = paintCanvas.strokes.size() - 1;
        System.out.println("Paths Loaded");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Not your answer, but do you really want `onDestroy()`?  This is usually only called if you explicitly `finish()` your activity.  `onPause()` or `onStop()` may be better choices.

Comment: @Simon yes, `onDestroy()` is called whenever the device is rotated. I tired `onStop()` and it was saving too often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Path` Objects are not serializable. I believe this was causing the error, to get around this I created a custom data structure that implements serializable to hold the instructions of each path and then constructed my paths off of that.